# how to make select query faster on Postgis

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgis

this query selects geometry _id by within the circle

```
 select tbl2.geometry_id from geometryTable tbl1
        join geometryTable tbl2 on  ST_Intersects(ST_Buffer(ST_centroid(tbl1.geometry)::geography, 1000)::geometry, tbl2.geometry)
    where tbl1.geometry_id = '112233'
```

this query works fine but it has taken too many times, more than 20 seconds. I need to make this query faster.

Comment: Please post output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) <your query>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the `tbl2` geometries that are within `1000` meters of `tbl1` geometries centroid, you can omit the buffer creation and rely on the distance directly by using [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

```
select tbl2.geometry_id 
from geometryTable tbl1
   join geometryTable tbl2 
    on ST_DWithin(ST_centroid(tbl1.geometry)::geography, tbl2.geometry::geography,1000, true)
where tbl1.geometry_id = '112233';
```

If this is not enough, you can create a spatial index on the centroid geography

```
CREATE tl1_centroid_geog ON tbl1 USING GIST(geography(ST_centroid(geometry)));
```

and eventually on tbl2 geography as well

```
CREATE tl2_geog ON tbl2 USING GIST(geography(geometry));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Index if the data is big.
Please read -[tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm) about the same.
Hope it helps